# Coded-UI external plugin support not working in VS2013, Vs2015 and VS2017

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I have implemented the Coded-UI external plugin support for my custom control using remote proxy and my implementation details are mentioned below,

**Application:**

```
public partial class Form1 : ControlTestApplication
{
    #region "Constructor"
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
public class ControlTestApplication : Form, IObserver
{
  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

    this.channel = new IpcChannel("CustomControl");
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(this.channel, false);

    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(InteropService), "ControlTestService", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
    Cache.Attach(this);
    base.OnLoad(e);
  }
}

internal class Communicator
{
    private static IControlInteropService thisInstance;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the instance of the test service.
    /// </summary>
    internal static IControlInteropService Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (thisInstance == null)
            {
                thisInstance = (IControlInteropService)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IControlInteropService), "ipc://Control/ControlTestService");
            }
            return thisInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have tried to get my control information using IContrlInteropService (InteropService) interface from another dll using below code,

```
public sealed class ControlTechnologyManager : UITechnologyManager
{
   public override IUITechnologyElement GetElementFromPoint(int pointX, int pointY)
   {
         var windowHandle = Utilities.WindowFromPoint(pointX, pointY);
         return this.GetControlElement(windowHandle, InteropService.GetElementFromPoint(int pointX, int pointY));
   }
}
```

which has thrown Invalid cast exception. Please find the below stack trace details,

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147467262 Message=Return argument has an invalid type.
>   Source=mscorlib StackTrace: at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.ValidateReturnArg(Object
>   arg, Type paramType) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PropagateOutParameters(IMessage
>   msg, Object[] outArgs, Object returnValue) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) at
>   CustomControl.WF.UITest.Services.IControlInteropService.GetElementFromPoint(Int32
>   pointX, Int32 pointY) at
>   CustomControl.WF.UITest.ControlTechnologyManager.GetElementFromPoint(Int32
>   pointX, Int32 pointY) in d:\svn\studio\src\trunk\Windows\Control.Windows\UITest\Src\SyncControlExtensionProvider\ControlTechnologyManager.cs:line
>   112 at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITechnologyManager.GetElementFromPoint(Int32
>   pointX, Int32 pointY, AutomationElement ceilingElement) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Framework.AbstractUITestService.GetTechnologyElementsFromRawElementsHierachy(List`1
>   managersHierarchy, List`1 rawElementsGroup, Int32 pointX, Int32
>   pointY, Boolean usePoints) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Framework.AbstractUITestService.GetTechnologyElementFromAE(AutomationElement
>   element, Int32 pointX, Int32 pointY, Boolean usePoints) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Framework.AbstractUITestService.GetElementFromPoint(Int32
>   pointX, Int32 pointY) InnerException:

**Note:**
This implementation working fine in VS2012. This issue occurs only in VS2013, VS2015 and VS2017 alone.

I have partially implemented the external plugin support for button which has attached below,

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6mYuvHmZAe-RjRJeUN5S2hzX28

You can reproduce the issue by following the below procedure,

1. Deploy the dlls and.pdb [Button.UITest & Button.TestService] files in following location

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\12.0\UITestExtensionPackages

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

2. Assert the button using Coded-UI test builder.
   Issue: It will throws the above mentioned exception.

This issue occurs when i try to get the control information from another dll[Button.TestService] using System.RunTime.Remoting.Proxies.

So, please suggest me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Hi @mjwills, Thanks for your reply. InteropService.GetElementFromPoint(int pointX, int pointY) throws the Invalid cast exception